# Apply images randomly at runtime in android studio

Tags: android

I have written code for 4 image buttons, and at runtime random images will be assigned to each such that 2 have same image and other 2 have same image. 
Right now, IB1 and IB3 will have same image and IB2 and IB4 will have same image.
IB1- ImageButton1 (IB1 is ID).
What I want is.. images should be applied randomly..like once I1 and I2 may have same image.. and next time I1 and I4 may have same image.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Random rnd = new Random(); 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageButton img1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.I1);
        // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...
        final String str1 = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(20);

        img1.setImageDrawable(
           getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str1, "drawable", getApplicationContext()))
        );

       final ImageButton img2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.I2);

       final String str2 = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(20);
       img2.setImageDrawable(
            getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str2, "drawable", getApplicationContext()))
       );

       final ImageButton img3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.I3);

       //final String str3 = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(20);
       img3.setImageDrawable(
           getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str1, "drawable", getApplicationContext()))
       );

       final ImageButton img4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.I4);

       //final String str4 = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(20);
       img4.setImageDrawable(
           getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str2, "drawable", getApplicationContext()))
       );
   }

   protected final static int getResourceID(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx) {
       final int ResourceID = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType, ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
       if (ResourceID == 0) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("No resource string found with name " + resName);
       } else {
           return ResourceID;
       }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this will be to first select any two images. You already have code for that in place. After you have your two images, select any two buttons. A simple random number selection will give you your two buttons (0-3 random number selection). Then you can simply set the image to those buttons.

**EDIT**

Here is some code to show how this can be achieved

```
final String imageResource1 = "img_" + rand.nextInt(20);
final String imageResource2 = "img_" + rand.nextInt(20);

List<ImageButton> imageButtons = new ArrayList<>();
imageButtons.add(IB1);
imageButtons.add(IB2);
imageButtons.add(IB3);
imageButtons.add(IB4);

//Now we select the buttons which will use the first image
int imageButtonIndex = rand.nextInt(4);
imageButtons.get(imageButtonIndex).setImageResource(
    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str1, "drawable", getApplicationContext())
);
imageButtons.remove(imageButtonIndex);

imageButtonIndex = rand.nextInt(3);
imageButtons.get(imageButtonIndex).setImageResource(
    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str1, "drawable", getApplicationContext())
);

//Now we just fetch and set the image 2 to the remaining buttons
imageButtons.get(0).setImageResource(
    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str2, "drawable", getApplicationContext())
);

imageButtons.remove(0);

imageButtons.get(0).setImageResource(
    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str2, "drawable", getApplicationContext())
);
```

There are many things that can be improved but this is a straight forward approach to achieve this

Comment: But how? How do I assign this `setImageDrawable` to random image buttons.

Comment: I am so sorry brother, I am unable to comprehend and link this code with mine.

Comment: Just replace what you did after setContextView in your onCreate method with the above code

Comment: If you want more understanding on how this is working feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

```
1. If there are 20 buttons. Button IDs are IB0, IB1, ... IB19.
2. If there are 10 Images. Image Names are img_0, img_1, ... img_9.
```

This small program will assign 10 images to 20 buttons, so that each image is used twice. Use Button instead of ImageButton, so that an Image is not required at the xml level.

```
ArrayList<String> image_list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            image_list.add("img_" + Integer.toString(a)); }}
    Collections.shuffle(image_list);

for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
    int btnId = getResources().getIdentifier("IB" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());
    Button btn = findViewById(btnId);
    int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(image_list.get(i), "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    btn.setBackgroundResource(drawableId);
    }

The end result will be 20 buttons with Images. 10 'PAIRS' in total, as in a 'match the cards' game.
It will be in random order each time you run it.
This is the smallest program I could come up with. Hope this helps.
```

Thanks for help from: stack overflow contributor, 'navylover'.

Comment: Can we have a talk over facebook or linked in??

Comment: I don't use those social networks. But I rewrote and tested a small program that will do exactly what you want. Check the edited answer.

Comment: One last little thing that you probably already know: If you are using Android Studio: When you set up those 20 Buttons, remove the text from the text field so that the word 'BUTTON' doesn't appear over each Image. I tested this program, it works perfectly... random each time.